State Space model with heteroskedastic disturbance - approximation of error term
We have a state-space model with a heteroskedastic disturbance term modelled according to some time-varying process (e.g. ARCH, GARCH etc.). The disturbance term is modelled according to e.g. $h_{t+1}=\alpha_0+\alpha_1 {\epsilon_t^*}^2$. Since term ${\epsilon_t^*}^2$ is unobserved, we can instead estimate $h_{t+1}$ as follows: $h_{t+1}=\alpha_0+\alpha_1\mathbb{E}[{\epsilon_t^*}^2| I_t]$ where $I_t$ is the all information up to time step $t$. This follows Harvey, Ruiz, and Sentana (1992). We can then follow Kim and Nelson $($2017$)$ $($Ch.6, pp.143-144$)$ in estimating $\mathbb{E}[{\epsilon_t^*}^2| I_t]$ by using the fact that $\epsilon_t^*=\mathbb{E}[\epsilon_t^*|I_t]+(\epsilon_t^*-\mathbb{E}[\epsilon_t^*|I_t])$ (1). We can then square the term $\epsilon_t^*$ and take the conditional expectation to obtain the expression $\mathbb{E}[{\epsilon_t^*}^2|I_t]=\mathbb{E}[\epsilon_t^*|I_t]^2+\mathbb{E}[(\epsilon_t^*-\mathbb{E}[\epsilon_t^*|I_t])^2]$ (2) given again by Kim and Nelson (2017) (Ch.6, pp.143-144).
I'm not sure how to go from (1) to (2).
This is what I've done so far.
If we square equation (1) we have:
(3) ${\epsilon_t^*}^2=\mathbb{E}[{\epsilon_t^*}|I_t]^2+({\epsilon_t^*}-\mathbb{E}[{\epsilon_t^*}|I_t])^2+2\mathbb{E}[{\epsilon_t^*}|I_t]({\epsilon_t^*}-\mathbb{E}[{\epsilon_t^*}|I_t])$
If we then take the conditional expectation, we have:
(4) $\mathbb{E}[{\epsilon_t^*}^2|I_t]=\mathbb{E}[{\epsilon_t^*}|I_t]^2+\mathbb{E}[({\epsilon_t^*}-\mathbb{E}[{\epsilon_t^*}|I_t])^2|I_t]$
where the cross-product cancels out because:
(5)$\mathbb{E}\Big[2\mathbb{E}[\epsilon_t^*|I_t]\times(\epsilon_t^*-\mathbb{E}[\epsilon_t^*|I_t])\Big| I_t\Big]=$
(6)$\mathbb{E}\big[2\mathbb{E}[\epsilon_t^*|I_t]\epsilon_t^*-2\mathbb{E}[\epsilon_t^*|I_t]^2\big| I_t\big]=$
(7) $\mathbb{E}[2\mathbb{E}[\epsilon_t|I_t]\epsilon_t^*|I_t]-\mathbb{E}[2\mathbb{E}[\epsilon_t^*|I_t]^2|I_t]=$
(8) $2\mathbb{E}[\epsilon_t^*|I_t]\mathbb{E}[\epsilon_t^*|I_t]-2\mathbb{E}[\epsilon_t^*|I_t]^2=0$.
In going from (7) to (8), I believe that the conditional expectation of a conditional expectation is just the original conditional expectation, since it equates to a known value as we are in time-step $t$ where all information up to $t$ is already known.
But if the above is correct, I'm still not sure how/why the conditional term in (4) falls away when comparing the expression to (2) as taken from the mentioned textbook.
Any help is appreciated.

This is the original poster. I was able to ascertain that the small derivation I stated is indeed correct. So the question is answered.
